# SharePoint online workflow to update list with totals from another list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-list

I have a list (ListA) that is populated by an InfoPath form:

**ListA** -

[image: ListA]

However I need to sum each column into another list (ListB) with totals of each ceremony - each time a new row is added or amended/deleted.. So I need this output:

**ListB**-

[image: ListB]

Any help on the workflow logic for SharePoint Designer would be much appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: whats the point of ListB if it always have 1 element? please rewise your lists structure

Comment: I need the totals in this format for our graphing app.. it's the summed totals of each column in ListA

Comment: i have to say that achieving this with workflows will be pretty hard..

Comment: try remote event handlers, here is step by step guide: https://www.sharepointeurope.com/handling-events-in-a-sharepoint-online-environment/

Comment: and you will need to attach to ItemAdded, ItemDeleted and ItemUpdating event for your ListA